# Reflection using generics

Tags: c#, reflection

I'd like to return the properties of a series of DbSet objects I have saved to a class using reflection, but in order to access this data in a single method I'd need to pass a variable as an accessor to return the properties of that object.

Currently I've managed to return the properties of all of the DbSet objects, but the code looks very DRY.

```
public DbSet<Foo> Foo {get;set;}
public DbSet<Bar> Bar {get;set;}

public List<string> GetPropertiesFoo()
{
    DbContext client = new DbContext();
    return client.Foo.GetType().GetProperties().Select(e => e.Name).ToList();
}
public List<string> GetPropertiesBar()
{
    DbContext client = new DbContext();
    return client.Bar.GetType().GetProperties().Select(e => e.Name).ToList();
}
```

My intention is to refactor this so that it accepts a DbSet name as an argument and returns a single list of properties, rather than a list of all properties.

Comment: Make the method `GetProperties<TSet>() where TSet: class` and use `client.Set<TSet>().GetType()...`

Comment: I'm not clear what you are trying to do here. Do you want all of the property types of the `Foo` and `Bar` types?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get a list of all of the properties of the models into list<string>; the models are foo, bar and exist in DbContext. But instead of getting each one by it's own method, I'm trying to work out how to do it in a single method.

Comment: So why does the function return a list of lists?

Comment: My b; corrected this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public List<Foo> GetFooFromBar(string bar)
{
     return = typeof(FooContext)//a list of DbSets (DbSet<Foo>, DbSet<Bar>)
    .GetProperties()
    .Where(e => e.Name == bar)//Filter based on the name of DbSet entered
    .GetType()//Get Type of the object returned (the DbSet with a matching name)
    .GetGenericArguments()[0]//Get the first item in the array of PropertyInfo
    .GetProperties()//Get a list of the properties of the DbSet within the Context
    .ToList();
    return bar;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something like this to do it all in one hit. Note this code is quite verbose so that each step can be explained:

```
// Make the method generic so we can use it on any context
public List<string> GetProperties<TContext>(string dbSetName = "")
    where TContext : DbContext // Make sure we have a Dbcontext
{
    var propertyNames = typeof(TContext)

        // Get all properties of context
        .GetProperties() 

         // Filter out so we only have DbSet<> types
        .Where(pi => pi.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
                     typeof(DbSet<>).IsAssignableFrom(pi.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()))

        // If a DbSet name has been specified, filter it out
        .Where(pi => string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbSetName) || pi.Name == dbSetName)

        // Get the generic type e.g. Foo
        .Select(pi => pi.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0])

        // Get the individual properties of the entity types
        .Select(t => t.GetProperties())

        // Get all of the property names
        .SelectMany(x => x.Select(pi => pi.Name)); 

    return propertyNames.ToList();
}
```

And use it like this:

```
// All properties for all sets
var allProperties = GetProperties<MyContext>();

// Only properties for the Foo set
var fooProperties = GetProperties<MyContext>("Foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be after something like this

```cs
public List<string> GetProperties(string model)
{
   var property = 
      this.GetType()
      .GetProperties()
      .Where(p=>p.Name == model)
      .FirstOrDefault();

   if(property == null) return IEnumerable.Empty<string>().ToList();
   return property
      .PropertyType
      .GetGenericArguments()[0]
      .GetProperties()
      .Select(p=>p.Name)
      .ToList();
}
```